# JpaRepository's deleteAllInBatchByField not deleting directly

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

JpaRepository has two methods `deleteAll()` and `deleteAllInBatch()`; the latter uses a `DELETE` statement, while the former fetches all entities into persistence context and deletes them individually, which ensures all validations and events are fired.

I want to use the in-batch variant with a where clause, however it still fetches the entities.

```java
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

    void deleteAllByField(String field);

    void deleteAllInBatchByField(String field);

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Foo where field=:field")
    void customDelete(String field);
}
```

The `deleteAllByField` and `deelteAllInBatchByField` in my case have the same effect: they execute a single `SELECT` and many `DELETE` statements. Also removing the `All` keyword in name has no effect. The `customDelete` works as expected, it executes a single `DELETE` statement.

Why could that be? If the `InBatch` or `All` keywords have no effect, why don't they produce an error, such as non-existent field after `By` would? Spring Data documentation doesn't mention delete methods at all.

Comment: Spring Data JPA [ignores any text between](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-methods-details.html#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) `delete` and `By` when deriving a query from a method name (but result limiting keywords such as Distinct, First and Top are applied).

Comment: But why is that? Doesn't make sense. It's only a source of confusion and errors.